# Java 8 get all employee having address start with P

Tags: java, filter, java-8, java-stream

I have employee and address class as below

```
class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    //getter and setter
}

class Address {
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    //getter and setter
}
```

Using java 8 filter I want to print all employees who are having city starting with P

What to add to below code to get emp of that filtered address

```
employees.stream()
    .map(Employee::getAddresses)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .filter(children -> children.getCity().startsWith("p"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dont flatmap on addresses then. You should permet another stream on the addresses if you want to keep your employee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `anyMatch` in `filter` instead of `map`ping :

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(employee -> employee.getAddresses().stream()
                 .anyMatch(adr -> adr.getCity().startsWith("p")))
         .forEach(System.out::println); // collecting not required to use forEach
```

Comment: OP can dispense with `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't map the `Employee` instances into their addresses if you want to print the `Employee`s that have an address that passes your filtering criteria:

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getAddresses()
                       .stream()
                       .anyMatch(addr -> addr.getCity().startsWith("p")))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Note that there's no reason to collect the `Stream` into a `List` if all you are going to do with the `List` is iterate over it with `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

It is case sensitive and the question is about 'P',

```
employees.stream()
         .filter(employee -> employee.getAddresses().stream()
                 .anyMatch(adr -> adr.getCity().startsWith("P")))
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```